# Adicionar Compilação da Biblioteca JNI com maven ou ant tasks

Tags: java, c, maven, ant

Estou criando um projeto Java com métodos nativos ([JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html)) sem ter que criar três projetos separados para isso. O meu objetivo é compilar tudo o que preciso de uma única vez.

Uso apenas uma DLL/SO nesse projeto gerada por um único arquivo em C.

Como adicionar esta etapa de compilação e mover a biblioteca para a pasta dist no `pom do maven` ou no `ant tasks`?

A minha indiferença por maven ou por ant tasks é que pretendo usar o netbeans para compilar isso, por tanto o que for mais fácil de adaptar será o que estou procurando.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Maven possui o [Native Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/) e o [NAR Plugin for Maven](http://maven-nar.github.io/index.html). Ambos possuem goals para trabalhar com compiladores C/C++, gerar headers com `javah`, etc.

Caso você precise de uma solução "faça você mesmo", [esse artigo](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Projects+With+JNI) (um pouco antigo) possui uma receita de bolo interessante. As classes são compiladas chamando o comando `make` através do [AntRun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) e ele te mostra como carregar e empacotar corretamente as bibliotecas nativas no Maven (contemplando o cenário em que você deseja fazer *build* para múltiplas plataformas).

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso o nar-maven-plugin para trabalhar com JNI, C e java num único projeto maven. Este plugin ficou por um tempo sem manutenção mas agora existe um grupo que retomou o desenvolvimento do projeto.

Este plugin cria automaticamente os cabeçalhos JNI a partir de métodos Java com a palavra reservada *native*, antes da compilação do código Java. Ele também cria automaticamente uma classe Java para carregar a DLL gerada, ajustando o nome da DLL de acordo com a versão (seguindo o padrão Maven). O plugin gera dois artefatos para um projeto JNI: o arquivo JAR e a DLL; assim é mais fácil manter casado o código C e Java.

Veja estes dois artigos, em português:

1 - [JNI: Java e C++ Num Único Projeto Maven](http://dacanal.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/jni-java-e-c-num-unico-projeto.html)

2 - [C++ e Maven: nar-maven-plugin](http://dacanal.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/c-e-maven-nar-maven-plugin.html)

Acho que o primeiro artigo é exatamente o que você procura. Ambos possuem código fonte para download.

Comment: Bem vindo as Stack Overflow. Procure contextualizar melhor a sua resposta, inserindo partes relevantes dos links que possam resolver o problema. Da maneira que está, caso os sites externos saiam ou dar ou mudem o link, sua resposta se tornará inútil.